# how to create chart by selecting from dropdown and date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

Another starter question...

I have to create a chart (bar, line etc) by selecting an attribute from the dropdown listbox and date picker. Attribute's value from dropdown goes to y axis and date to x axis. The attributes in the dropdown is coming from an json output (URL - currently http://localhost:8080/someproject)

I am looking something like in the link [Bar chart D3 libraries](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

I am able to get the x axis but i am struggling to put values on the y axis...

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxd5s01q/2/)

```
var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
console.log("as".selection);
$.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                console.log("%o",value)
                if (value['name'] == selection) {
                    var optionHtml = '';
                    for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                        var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                        var val = 'val' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                        optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '" data-val="'+value[val]+'">' + value[attr] + '</option>';
                    }
                    $("#listbox").css("width", "500px")
                    $("#listbox").css("height", "300px")
                    $('#listbox').append(optionHtml);
                    return false;
                }
                var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
                console.log(selectedOption);
});
```

Please ignore the data as of now, as the dropdown is getting populate correctly on my local desktop.

I am just looking for **the logic of putting the values of my attribute selected in the drop down list box on the y axis for the required date selected in the date picker.**

Apologies for not adding more code, due to company policy...

Comment: Any advice... I am looking for something like this.... http://bl.ocks.org/jhubley/ffcf5d544f13cd08a4b2

Answer (score 0):

you can use Visit https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-column-chart/ its very easy to use.